# Problem with "\href{URL}{URLname}"

Tags: hyperref, urls

Using the package hyperref, I can use \url to produce clickable URLs. But in the viewers I have their boundaries are very badly set. Example:[image]

Hence, I prefer to use \href{}{}, which works most of the time. But in the examples in this picture it crashes. This is a near minimal crashing example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

 %\url{https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_way}
\href{https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_way}{https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_way}

\end{document}
```

Here's the log:
[image]

What should I change?

Comment: It is probably the underscore character in the URL that trips you up. Try using the `url` package, or just escape the underscore with a backslash: `Spirit\_way`

Comment: @MichaelPalmer This solves it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mis-using the `\href` macro: The second argument should be a human-readable string, not some URL which may contain characters -- such as `_` ("underscore") -- that are *special* to TeX.

If you insist on showing the full URL, just use the `\url` macro, not the `\href` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\url{https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_way}

\href{https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_way}{Wikipedia page: Spirit Way}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you (a) insist on showing a full URL string that contains TeX-special characters and (b) for some reason don't want to use `\url{...}` directly, you *could* type (though I wouldn't recommend it!) `\href{https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_way}{\url{https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_way}}`.

Comment: Ok, but as stated, the boundaries \url produces are messed up - in any of my viewers.

Comment: @Ludi - Two questions: (1) Are you loading the `url` package with the options `hyphens`, `spaces`, and `obeyspaces`? (2) Why do you insist on showing the full URL? The whole point of using `\href` is *not* to have to show the underlying URL in the first place.

Comment: @Ludi - Incidentally, by "boundaries", do you mean the margins of the text block? Please clarify.

Comment: 1) No. how to do it? 2) I don't know whether my professor will immediately realise the URLs are clickable. If he thinks I am withholding the URLs he is bound to be angry.

Comment: I mean the blue boundaries shown in the pic produced by both my viewers. When using \url they interfere with the text of the URL. That is the only reason I chose \href. Those same boundaries are correct when using \href.

Comment: `\nolinkurl` instead of `\url` inside the second argument of `\href` avoids a nested link.

Comment: @Ludi - Regarding (1): just run `\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}` -- as is done in the code I provided. Regarding (2): You are *not* "withholding URLs": If the mouse pointer hovers over the link produced by `\href`, the URL will be shown -- at least that's the case with Acrobat.

Comment: @Ludi - Is anything preventing you from specifying the option `colorlinks` when loading the `hyperref` package?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - Thanks! A really good [!!] suggestion!

Comment: @Mico colorlinks works like a charm!

Comment: What is the difference between `\href` and `hyperref`?

Comment: @hola - A very good question. :-) Please post a *new query*, so that more potential answer-givers may see it and seize the chance to provide an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Mico [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572929/href-hyperlink-and-hyperref)