# `\href`, `\hyperlink` and `\hyperref`

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink, href, hypertarget

As per [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico)'s [suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384197/38244) (and my indomitable curiosity), here is the question:

> What are the differences among `\href`, `\hyperlink` and `\hyperref`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\url{https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_way}

\href{https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_way}{Wikipedia page: Spirit Way}

\hyperlink{https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_way}{Wikipedia page: Spirit Way}

\end{document}
```

And, what is the deal with `\hypertarget` anyway?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553769/2388

Comment: I guess `\url` is clear: It typesets the URL and links it. It sort of works like `\href{<url>}{\nolinkurl{<url>}}`, where `\nolinkurl{<url>}` just typesets the URL. `\href{<url>}{<text>}` typesets `<text>` and links it to `<url>`. `\hyperlink{<target name>}{<text>}` typesets `<text>` and links it to `<target name>`. A link target can be created with `\hypertarget{<target name>}{<text>}` inside your document. So `\hyperlink` can be used to refer back to a different, arbitrary part of your document that has been marked up with `\hypertraget`.

Comment: Then there is `\hyperref[<label>]{<text>}` which typesets `<text>` and links it to the target of the label `<label>` that you'll have generated with `\label{<label>}` somewhere in your document. (I'm not sure if that is technically accurate, but you can sort of imagine this as similar to `\hyperlink`, with `\label` automatically generating the corresponding `\hypertarget` for you.)

Comment: you have a question about three commands and an example code demonstrating three different commands?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Should I delete it?

Comment: @hola I was just suggesting you clarify it: are you asking about \href,\hyperref,\hyperlink or about \url, \href,\hyperlink, or about all four. But perhaps you could consider the question a duplicate of the one Ulrike links to in the first comment and close it for that reason?